# Adjusting for clustering and overdispersion in count models

Tags: r, count-data, overdispersion, clustered-standard-errors, quasi-likelihood

My question is specific to the estimation of `glm`'s and correcting for 'clustering' in a quasi-experiment (difference-in-differences). My outcome is counts of crimes. My cross-sectional unit is the precinct/department and I observe crime in those precincts/departments over several months. My goal is to estimate a basic Poisson model, then compare this model to other overdispersed generalizations, i.e., the quasi-Poisson and negative binomial.

I have overdispersion, and so I want to correct for that. However, I also want to account for the clustering. I estimated each model and adjusted the standard errors using the `vcovCL` function, clustering on `~precinct`. I did this for each `glm` model estimated.

Question:

Should I estimate the overdispersion and then multiply the standard errors in all models by this dispersion factor? Do other `glm`'s, i.e., `family  = "quasipoission"` do this adjustment for you?

Essentially, clustering at the unit-level deflates my standard errors, even with clusters well beyond 50. I don't want to *over*-adjust my standard errors, if that makes sense.

I appreciate anyone that can help me with this conceptually.

Comment: Why not use glmer() instead of glm() to account for clustering of counts within precincts? Then, if there is any evidence of overdispersion for the glmer() model, you could use the quasipoisson family within the glmer() model call. For glmer(), you need to use the lme4 package. This package also has a glmer.nb() function for thenegative binomial family.

Comment: I incorporate "precinct" and "month" fixed effects in all `glm` models (dummies for precincts and months). I haven't used this package but I will look into it.

Comment: If you are only interested in the precincts included in your study, then your current approach makes sense. However, if the precincts in your study are selected so as to be representative of a larger set of precincts which you are interested in, then treating precinct as a random grouping factor makes more sense.  In the latter case, glmer() would be appropriate.

Comment: Yes. Just for the precincts in my study. Does a quasi-Poisson approach adjust the standard errors accordingly? I assume a 'clustering' correction using `vcovCL` would be appropriate as well.